# How does Bonnie (& her friends) not know that Katherine isn't dead?

Tags: tv, the-vampire-diaries

Bonnie is an anchor to this world and the other side. So,

- Every dead supernatural must pass through her (when she experience pain).
- She is able to see everyone on the other side.

Even if Bonnie never bothered to find Katherine on the other side (I don't know how it works), Katherine never passed through her.

**How does Bonnie, at least, not know that Katherine isn't dead?**

Comment: note that, at the time of her death, Katherine was not anything supernatural, so Bonnie may have no way of knowing she didn't die.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield What!!! She is a Traveller..

Answer (score 0):

She saw Katherine seconds after she died.  Katherine forced herself back in to her body just saying "no, not yet.  I'm not ready."  Or something similar.  Beings don't have to go through Bonnie immediately.  So far as Bonnie knows, Katherine is just walking the Earth as a ghost; which we know some people (like Matt's sister) have been doing since they died in season 1.

Comment: After she saw Katherine, she told it to friends. And, talked like "She really don't want to die." Plus, after this event, Elena went to meet Katherine. It means they knew that Katherine hasn't been dead yet.

Answer (score -1):

Katherine was supernatural still. A traveler witch and a doppelganger. She would have to pass through bonnie. Its just a stupid plot hole.